# React-Query, useQuery is delivering stale data

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-query

I'm just trying out react-query for the first time, and I've now ran into something I am getting pretty frustrated with.

Following code:

```
const userSettingsQueryClientKey = "userSettings_queryClient";

export const UserSettingsContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const { data } = useQuery(userSettingsQueryClientKey, async () => {
        const request = new GetRequest<UserSettings>("/UserSettings/Get");
        const result = await request.get();
        return result.payload;
    });

    const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(async (settings: UserSettings) => {
        const updateRequest = new VoidPostRequest<UserSettings>("/UserSettings/Update");
        await updateRequest.post(settings);
        return settings;
    }, {
        onSuccess: (newData) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(userSettingsQueryClientKey, newData);
        }
    })

    return (
        <UserSettingsContext.Provider value={{
            settings: { ...data },
            updateSettings: async (settings: UserSettings) => {
                await mutateAsync(settings);
            },
        }}>
            {children}
        </UserSettingsContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

I am having lots of problems getting the

```
queryClient.setQueryData(userSettingsQueryClientKey, newData);
```

part to work.

I have properly debugged my code several times now. During the flow of my app:

1. The settings are initialized to `{ useOldVersion: true }`
2. At some point in time, a user will click a checkbox, and call `updateSettings` with `{ useOldVersion: false }`
3. The mutation properly posts this update to the server
4. The onSuccess is called, properly setting the query state to the new value.

However, after the `onSuccess` the `const { data }` I'm getting from my `useQuery` call still delivers the old, stale data. I verified all the previous steps with the debugger, and now I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any advice how to properly get the new state from the `useQuery` call?

Comment: Your code looks okay, updates from mutation responses are a valid concept, see: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses some minor things are: mutateAsync needs try/catch, use mutate unless you need promise chaining. I've never put data from react-query into context, as you can just call useQuery (or a custom hook abstraction) when you need the data. It will also keep the data up to date because it triggers refetches when a new subscriber mounts. Can you make a codesandbox reproduction that shows your issue? I can assure you that updates after mutations do work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found my very stupid bug. All the answers were helpful, but could never find the problem.

My app looked like this:

```
export default function App() {

  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <MyComponent />
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

This meant that the query client is constantly regenerated.

It works when it's moved out like this, so the value is persisted:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <MyComponent />
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Tried multiple solutions but could never think of this one. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **[refetchQueries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientrefetchqueries)** method exposed by QueryClient.
Your code would look something like:

```
 const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(async (settings: UserSettings) => {
        const updateRequest = new VoidPostRequest<UserSettings>("/UserSettings/Update");
        await updateRequest.post(settings);
        return settings;
    }, {
        onSuccess: (newData) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(userSettingsQueryClientKey, newData);
            queryClient.refetchQueries(userSettingsQueryClientKey);// this is new

        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it doesn't seem to help either. It's almost like no matter what I try in my onSuccess, the query itself does not care. I also tried invalidateQueries and put a breakpoint into my GET callback in the query, but it wasn't triggered either.

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way to notify the query has changed is through the use of `queryClient.invalidateQueries`.

You can see an example in the RQ [docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/optimistic-updates).

```js
const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(
  async (settings: UserSettings) => {
    const updateRequest = new VoidPostRequest<UserSettings>("/UserSettings/Update");
    await updateRequest.post(settings);
    return settings;
  },
  {
    onSuccess: (newData) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData(userSettingsQueryClientKey, newData);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(userSettingsQueryClientKey);
    }
  }
);
```